# combining stereo in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, stereo

Is it possible to combine the left and right channels of stereo output and then send the result to both left and right headphones?

I'm watching a video where only the right channel contains words and it's kind of annoying. So i'd like mono in both ears. My Macbook has this option in accessibility, but I'm yet to find it in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say if hardware was a possible solution.  I've got a "mono to stereo" mini-plug somewhere in my toolbox.  Darn'd if I can remember when or where I got it ...

Comment: combining stereo *in windows 7* :). But thanks I'll keep hardware in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem but solved it by forcing mono sound in my video player. I'm using VLC but I'm sure many other players support this.

Comment: oh well, I'll have to play the sound through my Mac *rolleyes* (I love how Apple stuff just works)

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan,

This would require cables and adapters.  The connection is complex as you have to get cables and adapters from a place like Radio Shack.

3.5mm stereo male jack to dual male RCA left and right (white/red).  Connect the dual male RCA left and right to a dual female RCA that ends in a single male RCA.  Connect the single male RCA (now stereo into mono) to a double female RCA.  Now reverse the process.  Connect to the other side of the double female RCA a single male RCA to dual female RCA (mono on left and right channels).  Connect each of the two female RCA to dual male left and right RCA (white/red).  Left and right channels don't matter since the audio is the exact same for both at this point.  Connect the 3.5mm male to a double female 3.5mm adapter.  Finally plug in your headphones or speakers to the female 3.5mm connection.

- 2 x 3.5mm male to dual RCA male (white/red)
- 2 x single RCA male to dual RCA female
- 1 x dual RCA female
- 1 x 3.5mm dual female

Happy mono listening on two channels.

Comment: Oh gee, I just just plugged the headphone out into my Mac's Mic in and then my headphones into my mac's headphone out. Of course Windows has the ability to play the input through the output,but the ability to make it mono and Mac OSX is the exact opposite, so i downloaded lineIn for Mac and in the Accessilbity preferences set the audio out to mono.